# .htaccess code for multiple page of same directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have near about 50 PHP page which is shown in address bar like -
http://www.example.com/STOP_WATCH/index.php
or
http://www.example.com/STOP_WATCH/second.php
for friendly url I was create a htaccess file with the following code-
`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ second.php?`
-I have to know the rule for show the page like -
http://www.example.com/STOP_WATCH/second.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You can take a look at [here](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/#removing-extensions).